# If-in statement testing for a list in nested lists not recognizing the first list is inside the second one when used in a function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

The if-in statement should print 'test', but it will not. Whenever I try a similar idea outside of a function, it works perfectly, as in the example at the bottom. I can tell the problem is with the if in statement, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

```
class Pawn:

    def __init__(self, num, pos, col, fmove):
        self.num = num
        self.pos = pos
        self.col = col
        self.fmove = fmove

w_pawn1 = Pawn(1, [1, 2], 'White', True)

def move(piece, typ):

    if typ == 'pawn':
        
        if piece.fmove == True:


            posmove = [[piece.pos[0], int(piece.pos[1])+1],
                       [piece.pos[0], int(piece.pos[1])+2]]

            Move = input('Where do you want to move?')

            print(Move)
            print(posmove)

            if Move in posmove:
                print('test')
                piece.pos = move

    else: pass



list1 = [1,3]
list2 = [[1,3],[1,4]]

if list1 in list2:
    print('ok')

output:ok
```

Comment: ``posmove`` is a list of lists, ``Move`` is a string. ``"Whenever I try a similar idea"`` - well, you're comparing apples to bananas, those cases are not remotely similar.

Comment: `input()` always returns a string. `"1"` is not the same as `1`.

Comment: But shouldn't Move be a list? Whenever I print it, it comes out like a list.-Nevermind I get it now. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you input a string that looks like a list (we cannot tell), but ``input`` returns a string, not a list, even it it prints like one.

Comment: Okay, so I just convert the string into a list and it will work?

Comment: If you're doing it correctly, then yes. You can easily try by setting ``Move`` to the desired list. If that works, then all that's left if to convert your input string to the same list.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I was able to convert it with json and it works now.